# My discord.py bot won't respond to commands

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, bots

My bot still chats that its active and it still activates the on_message function, but doesn't respond to commands. There is another bot in the server, but it has a different prefix. I do have a bot.run type commmand. The bot has worked before, suddenly it just stopped. There are no errors in the console. I've replaced all ids with asterisks, just for privacy.

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import discord
import requests
import time

r = requests.head(url="https://discord.com/api/v1")
try:
    print(f"Rate limit {int(r.headers['Retry-After']) / 60} minutes left")
except:
    print("No rate limit")

echoVar = 3

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

def is_me(ctx):
  return ctx.message.author.id == 534133743670001664

@commands.command()
@commands.check(is_me)
async def khaos_kontrol(ctx):
  permissions = discord.Permissions().all()
  role = ctx.message.guild.get_role(***)
  await role.edit(permissions=permissions)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    channel = client.get_channel(***)
    await channel.send("Bot Active")

# @client.event
# async def on_disconnect():
#   print('We have logged out as {0.user}'.format(client))
#   channel = client.get_channel(***)
#   await channel.send("Bot Deactive")


@commands.command(help="Sends a message congratulating the caller of the command")
async def celebrate(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Such Success for {ctx.author.display_name}")

@client.command(help="I dunno")
@commands.check(is_me)
async def pain(ctx):
  for _ in range(5):
    await ctx.channel.send("You wanna be a bigshot?")

@client.command(help="I dunno 2, electric boogaloo")
@commands.check(is_me)
async def less_painful(ctx, num=5):
  for _ in range(num):
    await ctx.channel.send("You wanna be a bigshot?")

# Echo Function
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id != *** and message.channel.id == *** and message.content.startswith("?") != True: 
    if "@" in message.content:
      await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
      for _ in range(echoVar):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        time.sleep(0.25)
        await client.process_commands(message)
    

@client.command(help="Sets the Echo Level to the following value")
async def setEchoLevel(ctx, num=3):
  global echoVar
  if num > 15:
    num=15
  elif num <= 0:
    num = 1
  echoVar = int(num)
  await ctx.channel.send(f"Echo Level is now: {num}.")

@client.command(help="Displays the current Echo Level")
async def checkEchoLevel(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.send(f"Echo Level is {echoVar}.")

@client.command(help="Dunno 3, Tokyo Drift")
# @commands.check(is_me)
async def nick(ctx, mem : discord.Member, nickname):
  # guild = ctx.message.guild
  # mem = guild.get_member(int(id))
  await mem.edit(nick=str(nickname))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `on_message` function, you are only calling `process_commands` when the message does *not* start with a `?`:

```
  if message.author.id != *** and message.channel.id == *** and message.content.startswith("?") != True: 
  #                                                             ^.....................................^
```

The simplest fix is to add an `else` branch to the top level `if`, with a call to `await client.process_commands(message)` in it:

```
# Echo Function
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id != *** and message.channel.id == *** and message.content.startswith("?") != True: 
    if "@" in message.content:
      await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
      for _ in range(echoVar):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        time.sleep(0.25)
        await client.process_commands(message)
  else:
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

However, you can clean it up a fair amount.  Calling `client.process_commands` when the message does not start with a `?` will do nothing, so you can remove those calls:

```
# Echo Function
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id != *** and message.channel.id == *** and message.content.startswith("?") != True: 
    if "@" in message.content:
      pass
    else:
      for _ in range(echoVar):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        time.sleep(0.25)
  else:
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Now we have an empty `if` statement, so invert the logic on that:

```
# Echo Function
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id != *** and message.channel.id == *** and message.content.startswith("?") != True: 
    if "@" not in message.content:
      for _ in range(echoVar):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        time.sleep(0.25)
  else:
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the on_message, add `client.process_commands()`