# My bot is no longer responding to commands

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, pycord

This was asked previously, but never answered (as in marked) and did not have the same specifics as me ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256856/my-discord-py-bot-wont-respond-to-commands))

For context, I was working on my bot, specifically on a command that add and removes roles, I restarted the bot, and it just stopped responding to commands. I say that instead of "stopped working" because it still works. It comes online, it can put its status up, and it responds to `on_message` functions. Any attempt at calling a command does nothing, it doesn't respond in chat, it doesn't give an error, throwing a print statement in the command shows that it doesn't even run the command.

I have already tried reverting the roles command because it happened right after, did not fix it. I removed the command entirely and the same problem occurred. I re-installed all my packages whether they related to discord or not and updated. Nothing fixed it.

I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm running the bot. I'm using Pycord. Here is some code that may be helpful, but I really don't know what would help resolve the problem

```
# Top of main.py file
import discord, random, json, os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.utils import find
# discord.py API docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

# ...
# unrelated code here
# ...

# I use cogs for my commands, here is the imports for all cogs
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.fun')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.msg')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.mod')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.games')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.role')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.misc')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.secretCommands')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands.msgTriggers')

# ...
# unrelated code here
# ...

# Bottom of main.py file
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

```
# Top of one of my cogs (fun commands cog)
import discord, json, randfacts, random
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint
from cogs import assets


class Fun(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

# ...
# unrelated code here
# ... 

# Bottom of one of my cogs (fun commands cog)
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Fun(client))
```

Comment: Do you have [the necessary intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) enabled? Try replacing `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True` with [`discord.Intents.all()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.all).

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder My bot is verified and cannot enable all intents as I don't have permission for some

Comment: Oh, I don't know what to do in that case. Try enabling them in [your Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), maybe?

Comment: This is possibly because [message content is going to be a privileged intent](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055) and your bot is verified. You will have to apply for this intent.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I have them enabled on my dev portal.

Comment: @Henry How would this prevent commands from working? I'll be sure the apply but I want to continue to search for a solution incase this isn't it. Could you explain how not having this intent enabled could cause this issue?

Comment: The bot needs access to message content to check if it begins with its command prefix. I'm assuming it won't respond to commands because of this, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Henry Hmmm I see what you're getting at but I'm inclined to believe it's something else. This is because it was working fine without messages intents before.

Comment: @goose.mp4, does your bot work now? Intents are like a permission to Discord's gateways/servers/some server-side things, databases etc. (I guess), so they won't work without them enabled. It needs to access messages and other things on Discord. The intents allow you to. The intents' updates are a pain in the neck and were for me too, but my bot worked after I enabled all possible intents and all I could see on my Dev Portal, but enabling them is apparently necessary.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I requested for Message Content Intent just now. In the mean time, do you know of any other reasons this could be happening? For more context, I am using Replit.com.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. This example is not minimal, nor does it contain any command definitions

Comment: @goose.mp4, I don't think there could be any more. I mean, there could be many, but none with the details you've currently shared. If something happens after the request is accepted/successful, you can always ask another question/come back here.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, I don't think the OP should include any command definitions. The question isn't about any and doesn't need any to be included. But yes, the code can be shortened.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I had every intent enabled already, but after reading the message in the dev portal, the Message Content Intent is not even enforced yet and there is currently no way to 'enable' it since it's not an option yet.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder The question is about commands not working, we need to see how those commands are defined and the most minimal example. This will make the question more helpful to others and can also eliminate the possibility that it was caused by a typo or other small error.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs If you read, the problem is the commands not working but as stated it literally randomly stopped working. The way the commands are set up clearly has nothing to do with it as they worked just fine previously and only stopped suddenly for an unknown reason, which is why I came to SO because I don't know said reason. It would be illogical to say that the commands are the issue when they were never touched and had previously worked.

Comment: I have read the question. It needs a [mcve]. Just because you think something is a certain way, it doesn't mean it is that way. Also, most of the code included is irrelevant to anyone coming here in the future, so that should also be trimmed down either way. We should be able to copy-paste the code in order to debug or reproduce it ourselves (omitting any tokens).

Comment: @goose.mp4, you may have to provide a [mre], but I don't think so. TheFungusAmongUs may be right; he has to specify which part he wants. But is the bot/command working after changing it to `discord.Intents.all()`? Just try changing to it, and run the bot. If it produces any errors, please share them. I don't know what errors it could possibly produce as your bot is verified.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder It gives an error `raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.` which is because of the new Message Content intent since you currently cannot get it enabled without applying (I've applied)

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I'm assuming it's the new intent since the other 2 are enabled. https://prnt.sc/MdxJnIeQpt6V (Screenshot of the portal page for my intents)

Comment: You'll have to apply for it I believe. Also you might be forgetting a `process_commands`. Try running your command, but `@`-ing your bot at the end of it. I believe that if the bot is mentioned in the message then it will be able to read it without the intent.

Comment: The problem has been fixed, the issue was solved with a discord server member of mine. It was an internal error with replit because it has its own package system and the shell which you can use for packages. When I restarted my bot, it updated the package and broke it. I had to go into shell, `pip uninstall` and then remove it from my replit packages. Regardless, thank you for the help everyone! I'm not aware of how to close this question since there is no answer I can mark.